# how can I save text content as jcr:data property in aem?

Tags: java, groovy, osgi, aem

I have a node that contains lots of text stored as its `jcr:data` property. I can read from it and display it in the console by this `groovy` code:

```
InputStream content = node.getNode("jcr:content").getProperty("jcr:data")
                     .getStream()
println(content.text) //it shows me its content = text
```

Now I want to change some characters in this text and set it back again as a `jcr:data` property. I tried doing:

```
ValueFactory factory = session.getValueFactory()
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Charset.forName("UTF-8")
                     .encode(content.text.replaceAll("xx", "yy").array())
Binary binary = factory.createBinary(is)
Value value = factory.createValue(binary)
node.setProperty("jcr:data", value)
```

But this raises an error:

```
unexpected token: Binary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to import javax.jcr.Binary ?

**Esit:** You are missing a parenthesis before .array()

Comment: yes I have this imported... it still doesn't see the `Binary` though... But maybe there's some other way around to write my own content to `jcr:data`, instead of using `Binary`?

Comment: hey man, missing parenthesis right after array() did the trick, thank you for noticing it!